# Composer update with FOSUserBundle with ~2.0@dev having issue

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony 2.3.* version for my symfony project, ~2.0@dev FOSUserBundle. Today when I did composer update and try to open register page, Its giving me error like **Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType"**

When I search through FOSUserBundle latest commits, I found that, for symfony 3 support they have made some changes in forms (They have used LegacyFormHelper). [You can check it here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/861df9330d04b0d5665616743277fa14cd1ad6a7)

I am not sure what to do to resolve this issue.

It was working like charm till date. I've seen this issue today once update the composer.

Comment: You should not be using a development version.  Check the github site for tagged releases.  Last I looked there was an alpha release.

Comment: @cerad Thanks. I switch to alpha release. then it was showing me different error for Gregwar bundle. and I switched gregwar bundle to version 1.1 and it solved

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType` in your FormType or in your controller if you didn't create Form Classes.

> To denote the form type, you have to use the fully qualified class name - like TextType::class in PHP 5.5+ or Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType. Before Symfony 2.8, you could use an alias for each type like text or date. The old alias syntax will still work until Symfony 3.0. For more details, see the 2.8 UPGRADE Log.